# htaccess problems and general regex

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm having problems with my htaccess rewrites.

the line is :

```
RewriteRule ^sports/([^/\]+)/?([^/\]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=sports&title=$1&go=$2&d=$3 [L]
```

for this url : `http://localhost/host/sports/other/` -> it will result:

```
***object(url)[3]
  public 'v' => string 'sports' (length=6)
  public 'title' => string 'other' (length=5)*** ( these are the var_dump of Gets);
```

so far for this url, its all fine BUT for this URL:
http://localhost/host/sports/baseball/aliasss/
it will results : 404 not found, i have to modify the regex and add a '.' so:

```
RewriteRule ^sports/([^/\]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=sports&title=$1&go=$2&d=$3 [L]
```

it works fine then. but if i keep the dot, and check the old url, with 2 folders only, it will results this :

```
object(url)[3]
  public 'v' => string 'sports' (length=6)
  public 'title' => string 'basebal' (length=7)
  public 'go' => string 'l' (length=1)
```

if you see the link is : `/sports/basebal/l` instead of `/sports/baseball`, 1 letter is missing from the query, HELP!
thanks :)

---

it worked fine after i added two lines n two cases :

```
RewriteRule ^sports/([^/\]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=sports&title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sports/([^/\]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=sports&title=$1&go=$2&d=$3 [L]
```

but i dnt think this is the right way, that means if i want another level i have to add another line ...humph

Comment: you have to escape the forward slashes with backslashes like `[^\/]+`

Comment: if you want to match a real dot you have to escape it too, otherwise the dot matches any character

Comment: actualy the letter doesnt have to be dot , it can be any letter, then the 3rd level slash will work fine, if i dnt add this, the third level slash will give me a 404 error. and if i add any letter(doesnt have to be dot(sorry for this)) the third level will work, by then with the(dot) if i go back to the second level slash like "/sports/2ndlevel/" it will give me page not found, but remains inside my framework where i extracted the GET values, and saw that the queries are v=sports, title=2ndleve(notice the missing l(last letter)), go=l(the missing l is here)

Comment: but anyway, maybe these expressions are wrong, can anyone give me a correct way to add this mod_rewrite and makes wit work perfectly?

Comment: what i need is : 
1- i have this url : index.php?v=sports&title=title&go=3&sid=1
the v is categories, the title is the title of the category, the go is the article inside that category, the sid is the page of that article. so it will look like

xxxxxxx/sports/basketball/bla_article/page_2/

Comment: but still keeping the parent pages work fine, all the example i looked for caused me 404 or errors. <br />
so if want to go to /sports/basketball/ it remains working, n wont break

Comment: @lbu nope, didnt work, the expression works fine for a two levels, withouht the mighty dot, if i go to the third level without that mighty dot it will give me 404, if i add that mighty dot to the 2nd level expresison, it works, but then the 2nd level stops working:(

Answer (score 1):

in your case I think I would use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sport/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/$ test.php?v=sport&a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
```

but usually I prefer

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?get=$1
```

and then parsing all the url with `php`

in your code you make few mistakes like `[^/\]+` .... usually you have to escape the forward slashes with backward ones like I've mentioned above,

in this case `[^\/.]+` you don't need the dot, because the `[^\/]`  expression matches anything except the forward slash

you don't need `/?` (optional forward slashes) because the text between them is not optional and you will probably get the whole url as `$1` .... maybe just the last one is useful

Comment: i thought about parsing the url in the php, but wasnt sure if thats a good technique, i love following the standards, but no forum i looked at gave me the standards of mod_rewrite.

Comment: can i learn more about the 2nd n the 3rd lines you used ?:) whats that for

Comment: @Emad checks if the url is file (2nd) or directory (3rd) ... if you have let's say `sport/template/style/style.css` and an optional forward slash you will not be able to load that css

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1&title=$2&go=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1&title=$2&go=$3&sid=$4 [L]